# Fontawesome icon text appears instead of icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

jquery 3.3.1

I'm building an anchor tag dynamically:

```
 var link = $("<a>");
        link.attr("href", "#");
        link.text("My anchor" + ' <i class="fas fa-people-carry"></i>');
```

The following produces the literal text 'My anchor i class="fas fa-people-carry"/i' instead of the text and actual icon for the anchor tag.

How do i make the actual icon appear inside the anchor tag along side my text?

Comment: use `link.html()` instead of `link.text()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need jQuery [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
link.html("My anchor" + ' <i class="fas fa-people-carry"></i>');
```

Some clarification about [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

> ... be aware that this method escapes the string provided as necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls the DOM method .createTextNode(), *does not interpret the string as HTML*

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `link.text()`, try `link[0].innerHTML = "My anchor" + ' <i class="fas fa-people-carry"></i>'`

You want HTML to parse the text you input as HTML, hence the `innerHTML` property is modified.